# SQL group by Custom grouping sets within a group by column

Tags: mysql, sql-server, group-by, grouping, vertica

Is custom grouping possible in **Vertica** where we need to group by not just a column but also just set of data within the group by column?

I may not be able to present my question properly but the sample data and the expected output would help understand my question.

Sample data can be created with the use of WITH below.

```
;WITH Sample(DayNo, Amt) AS
(
    SELECT 1,10.0 UNION
    SELECT 2,15.0 UNION
    SELECT 3,9.0 UNION
    SELECT 4,6.0 UNION
    SELECT 5,15.0 UNION
    SELECT 6,5.0 UNION
    SELECT 7,2.0 UNION
    SELECT 8,1.0 UNION
    SELECT 9,8.0 UNION
    SELECT 10,4.0
)
SELECT DayNo, Amt FROM Sample ORDER BY DayNo;
```

So there are just 2 columns DayNo (which is basically a date without time) and Amt (which is amount for that DayNo).

I want Sum(Amt) grouped by DayNo but for set of days. For eg:
If i want Sum(Amt) for a group of 2 consecutive days, then the expected output is:

```
DayNo SUM(Amt)
1-2     25
3-4     15
5-6     20
7-8     3
9-10    12
```

But if i want Sum(Amt) for a group of 3 consecutive days, then the expected output is:
Desired Result

```
DayNo SUM(Amt)
1-3     34
4-6     26
7-9     11
10-12   4
```

Note that the data may have multiple rows for same DayNo and not just 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *integer division* to group by:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST((((DayNo - 1) / 3) + 1) * 3 - 2 AS CHAR(4)), '-',
              CAST((((DayNo - 1) / 3) + 1) * 3 AS CHAR(4)))
           AS DayNo, 
       SUM(Amt)
FROM Sample 
GROUP BY (DayNo-1) / 3
```

This will group days 1, 2, 3 in one group, days 4, 5, 6, in next group. etc.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c38af/11)